# Bonificación de asociación

Tags: discusión, reputación

Buenos días, quería saber que es exactamente la Bonificación de asociación, pues hace poco me otorgaron +100 en mi reputación por esto, además quería saber sí existen otro tipo de bonificaciones que se pueda obtener y como haría para optenerlas. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Esto está descripto en la ayuda: [¿Qué es la reputación? ¿Cómo se gana (y se pierde)?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recibes el bono de asociación en todas tus cuentas de sitios de la red StackExchange cuando alcanzas 200 puntos de reputación por primera vez en cualquiera de los sitios. Esto es como un premio porque has probado un aprendizaje mínimo del funcionamiento de la red, y para que no tengas que luchar mas por los privilegios básicos en cada sitio al que te has afiliado.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141649/149992